# Django - Slugify get lookup

Tags: django, django-queryset, slug

If I had an object with the name `Object 1` and I wanted to `get()` that object, but I was trying to get it with a slugified name `object-1`, is there any way to do this? Something like:

```
Model.objects.get(name__slugify = slugifiedname)
```

I want to avoid adding an extra slug field to my model if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to put some restrictions on the value of the 'name' field only allowing [-A-Za-z]+, but you could do:

```
def my_request(request, name):
    un_slugified_name = name.replace('-', '')
    objects = MyModel.objects.get(name=unslugified_name)
```

However, the name you pass through the querystring would have to be exactly what's in the database. YMMV. My advice, use a SlugField :)

Answer (score 2):

Slugify is a Python function. To achieve your goal, Django would have to fetch the complete database (with at least the pk and the `name` field), calculate the slug for each row and compare this to the given parameter. And this would be very imperformant, so:

TLDR: No

Comment: agree with you, but if the lookup by slug is *really* important for the OP, it could be added a new db column to keep track of that. Not a best practice, but it can be done.